# what is the most common English word you hear when you talk with others

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, spoken-english

I would like to know,
what is the most common word you hear when you talk with others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English), the most common word in English seems to be 'the'. The list is based on *written* publications, but I see no reason why another *spoken* word should be more popular than 'the'. Words like 'yes' and 'no' are likely to be used in speech much more than in writing, but not enough to compete with 'the'.